# What are the definite things to do in order to deploy ASP.NET MVC 3 (Razor) app on server

Tags: c#, .net, iis, web-config, web-deployment

I have created a

- ASP.NET MVC 3 app using .net framework 4

  which is working fine with
- Visual Studio inbuilt Casini Server

.

As I don not have IIS , I am trying to deploy the app on another system having **IIS 5.1**  and **.Net framewrok 4.0 client profile**.

I am able to see the directory listing but the moment I type the controller path it's not working. What am I missing?

> **Could this be due to framework client profile**
> **or Web.confif File**
> **Or due to folder permission** (Though I tried giving all the permission to everone)
>
> Do I need to Install ASP.NET framewrok on Server for running razor app

Comment: Have you done the wildcard mapping in IIS? Here we go http://itscommonsensestupid.blogspot.com/2008/11/deploy-aspnet-mvc-app-on-windows-xp-iis.html

Comment: No , I am not aware of the Wildcard mapping, googling now, please share if u have any pointers though. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

ASP.Net MVC requires the full .NET profile. The client profile won't be sufficient.

> **NET4 Client Profile:**
>   Always target NET4 Client Profile for all your client desktop applications (including Windows Forms and WPF apps).
>
> **NET4 Full framework:**
>   Target NET4 Full only if the features or assemblies that your app need are not included in the Client Profile. This includes:
>
> - If you are building Server apps. Such as:
>           o ASP.Net apps
>           o Server-side ASMX based web services
> - If you use legacy client scenarios. Such as:
>           o Use System.Data.OracleClient.dll which is deprecated in NET4 and not included in the Client Profile.
>           o Use legacy Windows Workflow Foundation 3.0 or 3.5 (WF3.0 , WF3.5)
> - If you targeting developer scenarios and need tool such as MSBuild or need access to design assemblies such as System.Design.dll

-- [Source](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jgoldb/archive/2010/04/12/what-s-new-in-net-framework-4-client-profile-rtm.aspx)